# How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL from and up to some specific characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, regexp-substr

i am using oracle sql. i would like to substr starting from characters XY0 and include 2 or 3 more characters until '-' sign in the string

These characters may be anywhere in the string.

Original

| column_value |
| --- |
| 1st Row - Error due to XY0066- Does not fit -Not suitable |
| 2nd Row -Error due to specific XY0089- Will not match |
| 3rd Row -Not in good cond XY0215- Special type error |

Extraction should be

| result |
| --- |
| XY0066 |
| XY0089 |
| XY0215 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos) AS code
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         INSTR(value, 'XY') AS start_pos,
         INSTR(value, '-', INSTR(value, 'XY') + 2) AS end_pos
  FROM   table_name
);
```

or

```sql
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(
         value,
         INSTR(value, 'XY'),
         INSTR(value, '-', INSTR(value, 'XY') + 2) - INSTR(value, 'XY')
       ) AS code
FROM   table_name;
```

or using regular expressions, which is shorter to type but will run much slower:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'XY[^-]*') AS code
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, 'Error due to XY0066- Does not fit -Not suitable' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Error due to specific XY0089- Will not match' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Not in good cond XY0215- Special type error' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| ID | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XY0066 |
| 2 | XY0089 |
| 3 | XY0215 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XNXmIR9J)